# NodeJs: Data Transformers like in Laravel PHP Framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, sequelize.js

I've created multiple REST API projects using the Laravel framework and basing my code structure on the Laracasts tutorial. However we are deciding to move some projects using NodeJs as a backend. I'm beginning to learn node and I'm trying to replicate it in Node. I was able to do it for a singe object response but for multiple objects I can't seem to make it work.

Here is my controller:

```
index(req,res) {
    User
      .findAll()
      .then(function(users){
        res.json(api.respond(transfomer.transformCollection(users)));
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        res.json(api.respondWithError('users not found',error));
      });
  }
```

api controller:

module.exports = {

```
  // response w/o error
  respond: function(data,msg,status) {
    if (msg == null) {
      return {
        'status': status || true,
        'data': data
      };
    } else {
      return {
        'status': true,
        'message': msg,
        'data': data
      };
    }
  },

  // response with error
  respondWithError: function(msg,error) {
    var self = this;
    var status = false;
    var data = {
      'error': error
    };
    return this.respond(data,msg,status);
  },
};
```

transformer.js

```
module.exports = {

  // single transformation
  transform (user) {
    return {
      'id' : user.id,
      'username': user.username,
      'firstname': user.firstname,
      'lastname': user.lastname,
      'address': user.address,
      'phone': user.phone,
      'mobile': user.mobile,
      'status': user.status
    };
  },

  //
  transformCollection(users) {
    var self = this;
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= users.length; i++) {
        data.push(this.transform(users[i]));
    }
    return data;
  }

};
```

sample output

```
{
  "status": true,
  "data": [ 
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "b@email.com",
        "firstname": "Jon",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "address": "Homes",
        "phone": "+966501212121",
        "mobile": "+966501212121",
        "status": "NOT VERIFIED"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "b@email.com",
        "firstname": "Jon",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "address": "Homes",
        "phone": "+966501212121",
        "mobile": "+966501212121",
        "status": "NOT VERIFIED"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "b@email.com",
        "firstname": "Jon",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "address": "Homes",
        "phone": "+966501212121",
        "mobile": "+966501212121",
        "status": "NOT VERIFIED"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "b@email.com",
        "firstname": "Jon",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "address": "Homes",
        "phone": "+966501212121",
        "mobile": "+966501212121",
        "status": "NOT VERIFIED"
    },
  ]
}
```

Sorry for asking this as I'm a bit newb with node. Is it possible to achieve that output as I tried different ways but Im still getting errors. Btw I'm using sequelize for the database.

Thanks.

Comment: In your controller you are calling `transform(user)` but you have `users`, not `user`.

Comment: I don't know Larval, but you can read about `middleware` available on the popular nodejs frameworks like `express`, I guess they can help you achive what you want. And on a side note, you can drop the `$` prefix for variables :)

Comment: @RonDadon I don't think this is middleware. I used middleware for jwt token authentication on this code. It is just transforming data. Loop through the multiple objects returned from the db and format each object the way we want from the format.

Comment: you are calling `transform` instead of `transformCollection`

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @piotrbienias I get an empty data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```js
const options = {
    raw: true, 
    attributes: ['id', 'name', 'code', 'createdAt','updatedAt']
};

country.findAndCountAll(options).then(querySnapshot => {
    const total = querySnapshot.count;
    resolve({
        docs: querySnapshot.rows, 
        total: total
    })  
}).catch((err) => {
    reject(err)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer to my question since sequelize is returning the results as an object with additional properties aside from the database results I had to modify the controller to set and convert the results to raw in order for me to get the array of objects from the query results from the database.

```
index(req,res) {
    User
      .findAll({ raw: true }) // added "raw: true"
      .then(function(users){
        res.json(api.respond(transfomer.transformCollection(users)));
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        res.json(api.respondWithError('users not found',error));
      });
  },
```

This will return the array of objects from the database and from there the data transformer is working properly. Thank you for all the help.